# How do I correct bad arguments to a Scala constructor?

Tags: scala, constructor, nullable

I have a Scala class as shown:

```
class MyClass(title: String, value: Int) {
   ...
}
```

If the constructor is called with a `title` value of `null`, I would like to set `title` to the empty string instead. How can I do that? Is there a cleaner way than forcing `title` to be private and providing a getter?

```
def getTitle: String = if (title == null) "" else title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands your `title` value is just a constructor parameter so it is not accessible from outside (did you omit a `val`?). You can use this fact to compute the real `title` member like this:

```
class MyClass(_title: String, val value: Int) {
  val title = if (_title == null) "" else _title
  ...
}
```

This guarantees that `title` is not `null` in any instance of `MyClass`

---

For completeness, here is the alternative factory method implementation:

```
trait MyClass {
  def title: String
  def value: Int
}

object MyClass {
  protected class MyClassImplementation(val title: String, val value: Int) extends MyClass {}

  def apply(title: String, value: Int) =
    new MyClassImplementation(if (title == null) "" else title, value)
}
```

The only way to create an instance of `MyClass` is via the factory method, so the `null` check is always called.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a factory method that provides the desired value. Often, in Scala, this is done in the companion object:

```
object MyClass {
  def apply( title: String, value: Int ): MyClass =
    new MyClass( if (title == null) "" else title, value)
}
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that `title` is not `null` because you can still do `new MyClass(null, 0)`. To do this you need to have a `public` `trait` and a `private` implementation inside the object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using nullable variables that requires constant checking if-not-null, Scala encourages you to use `Option` where a value can be "none".
One way of achieving this is to use a secondary-constructor:

```
class ClassX(title: Option[String]) {
  def this(title: String) {
    this(Option(title))
  }
}
```

And if you have to use a nullable variable, you could use the factory mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to use `null`, but we're interfacing with some Java libraries and ugly JSON.